# Cocoa Menu Bar Agent app With a Helper cocoa app and triggered ON from Main cocoa app, its Gone in NOT RESPONDING

Tags: macos, cocoa, helper

Here i m making an Cocoa Menu Bar Agent app.now the question is The Cocoa Main App Referencing an another Helper App and i used NSBundle and Workspace to launch this Helper app via Main Apps ON (ON|OFF) Button.Gone in NOT RESPONDING situation for 2 Min after that working normal.
how we can do that its not gone in This situation.
the helper app is just dragged in main app.

**ON Button->**

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *helperAppPath = [[mainBundle bundlePath]
                               stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/Resources/helperapp.app"];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:helperAppPath];
```

Q.which entitlements have to set or in which application?
Q.Save It from crash(Not Responding).

---

```
IMP Question is that -> .Note that NoW i watched at activity monitor there is showing debugserver919, in Parent Process. instead of launched1 tell me what i can do?
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Implemented Answer***
There the above mention code is used for less then MacOS 10.6
and for 10.6 and above we can use the code

```
- (void)launchApplicationWithPath:(NSString *)path
{
    // As recommended for OS X >= 10.6.
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] respondsToSelector:@selector(launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:)];

       [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO] options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:nil error:NULL];

    // For older systems.
    // return [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:path];
}
```

And How to call this method:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *helperAppPath = [[mainBundle bundlePath]
                               stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/Resources/helper.app"];

    [self launchApplicationWithPath:helperAppPath];
```

Through This code your helper app launch well and not Gone in NOT RESPONDING condition oak thanks welcome.